# Code works on Windows JDK 7 but not on Linux JDK 7

Tags: java, linux, windows, encryption, java-7

The following code works beautifully in Oracle's JDK 7 on Windows but fails with the following error on Linux: `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher` at the line `Cipher.doFinal(ciphertextArray)` This is using the exact same Jar file with the exact same command line, etc. ***The values for text and password are coming from the command line though and I suspect the issue is somewhere here, I just have no idea where...***

```
String saltD = text.substring(0,12);
String ciphertext = text.substring(12,text.length());

// BASE64Decode the bytes for the salt and the ciphertext
Base64 decoder = new Base64();
byte[] saltArray = decoder.decode(saltD);
byte[] ciphertextArray = decoder.decode(ciphertext);

// Create the PBEKeySpec with the given password
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.trim().toCharArray());

// Get a SecretKeyFactory for PBEWithSHAAndTwofish
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptionMethod);

// Create our key
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

// Now create a parameter spec for our salt and iterations
PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(saltArray, ITERATIONS);

// Create a cipher and initialize it for encrypting
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionMethod);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

// Perform the actual decryption
byte[] plaintextArray = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextArray);
return new String(plaintextArray);
```

Comment: To ensure it is not a bug, I would run this with the latest version of each. I suspect 1.7.0_09-icedtea is too old.

Comment: so, why not use the one that is working ;)

Comment: Ok, so I just installed the same JDK on another test machine and it ruled that out. So I adjusted the question. But I do now remember reading something somewhere about needing to do something to the command line arguments because there's a subtle difference between Windows and Linux. I just can't remember what, when, where, or how :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the text string contained "$" characters in it, and from the command line in Linux these are escape characters. They need to be converted to "\$" in the String itself.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the observation is due to the difference in the default charsets on the two platforms.

You need to ensure that `String` to `byte[]` conversions (and vice versa) are performed using a *specified* charset instead of relying upon platform defaults.